# Is it practically possible to make an air conditioner more energy efficient?

Tags: experimental-physics, energy-conservation, electromagnetic-induction

I have had this thought for a long time that an air conditioner is connected to an exhaust device that pumps hot air away.

However theoretically it should be possible to channel that air flow into another turbine that activates an electromagnetic current generator so we could save a lot of wasted energy.

However this concept is not applied anywhere I could see.

Is there any possible flaw in this concept? Because if no it should have been applied already as the world is quickly depleting its energy reserves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is correct for these reasons:

1. an air conditioner typically pumps heat from one stream of air, into another stream of air.  [Sometimes the stream being heated goes from outside to outside](https://www.brighthubengineering.com/hvac/55241-how-the-window-air-conditioner-works/), while the stream being cooled goes from inside to inside.  [Alternatively, the stream being heated can go from inside to outside](https://patents.google.com/patent/US6658860), while the stream being heated goes from outside to inside.  This second case is very rarely used.
2. a heat engine (e.g., a turbine or thermoelectric generator) can extract energy from a temperature difference.  In either of the two cases above, there is a temperature difference between the outflowing air and the inflowing air. The greater the temperature difference, the more energy can be extracted. In the outside-to-outside case, the temperature difference is relatively large.  In the outside-to-inside case (which uses a counter-flow cooler), the temperature difference can be quite small, leaving very little extractable energy between the inflow and the outflow.  That means the counter-flow cooler is substantially more efficient than the standard design.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have misunderstood how air conditioning systems work. They do not pump hot air out. Instead they cool (and often add moisture to) incoming air. The cool incoming air may then displace warm air from inside the building, but this warm interior air will not usually be any hotter than the air outside the building, so no energy can be extracted from it.

If the interior air *is* hotter than the exterior air then this must be because the building is being heated by an external heat source, which will usually be sunlight. In this case, it will be more efficient to use photovoltaic cells to extract energy from the sunlight directly, rather than trying to extract energy from the warm interior air.

Comment: But whenever there is an AC i always find an exhaust that blows hot air constantly from it. Atleast wherever i have been